# why CRON scheduler is not worked in NiFI

Tags: apache-nifi

i have used ListFTP processor with scheduling parameters as mentioned below:

```
scheduling strategy is CRON
run schedule is 0 30 23 ? * * *
```

this does not run at each start of every month. is the CRON format something wrong?

But when i tried using the link [http://www.cronmaker.com/][1], 
it provided like **0 30 23 1/1 * ? ***

is there any differences between these two CRON? please enlighten me.

Comment: both should run every day (including first day of month) at 23:00

Comment: The last * is not needed. Simply you can try with 0 30 23 * * *

Answer (score 0):

Nifi uses [Quartz scheduler](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-core/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/scheduling/QuartzSchedulingAgent.java) which has different fields than regular cron tab

Crontab Syntax is ([ref](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/))-

```
* * * * * command(s)
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

While Quarts Scheduler's fields are , [according to nifi documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html)

[image]